# how to add a copy buton on menu context of folder in jumplist ON Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

Please help me!

I using win 11. how to can i add a copy button when i right click on on folder of jumlist as same in win 7 ?

Thank all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhZ3r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMmAJ.png)

Help me please if can! thank